# aws sync two s3 buckets with two root key sets / credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization

I am trying to sync two s3 buckets belonging to different accounts. I  installed aws cli in my machine and I have one key (buket1) set in .aws/credentails like this

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = dsdsdsda
aws_secret_access_key = dsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsds
```

I would like to run command

```
aws sync s3://bucket1  s3://bucket2
```

How do I add credentails to bucket2 for aws cli?

Comment: You could create an IAM role and grant access to it on each of the buckets.

Comment: @idabbay beside an IAM. Is it possible I can sync  two bucket with root key set for two different accounts ?

Comment: maybe but I don't know that for sure. If it's possible at all, it would involve setting a policy on the bucket.  Maybe if you can find the urns for the root accounts, you could put that in the policy. I'd check right now but I'm at an amusement park :)

Answer (score 0):

idgabbay is right -- IAM now has cross-account access features, and you also have S3 bucket policies, so between the two you should be able to grant a single account rights into both accounts/buckets.

Your `aws s3 sync` call cannot accept two sets of credentials at the same time, so adding another profile to your credentials file won't help.

Here is the aws page on cross-account access:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/roles-walkthrough-crossacct.html

A policy for granting other accounts access to one of your buckets would look like this (Note the second principal line is for a root account like you need):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/Alice",
                "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root"]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The above is taken from http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxPOJBY6FE360K/IAM-policies-and-Bucket-Policies-and-ACLs-Oh-My-Controlling-Access-to-S3-Resourc